# Flutter PageStorage, or preserving scroll position for SliverList

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-web

I'm trying to preserve the scroll position of the sliverlist when user navigates away and comes back to the page. not sure how to do this? with listview, i see examples using pagestoragekey, but nothing for slivers